# SPI communication between two Ethernet Shields (W5100)

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet, communication, spi

I am a newbie to the world of IoT, I want to ask...

Is it possible to connect two Ethernet shields with SPI? And if yes, how can I codes them?

I have reference from http://www.gammon.com.au/spi and I've tried SPI communication between two Arduino Unos send & receive any data type..

Now.. I want to put Ethernet Shields to each Arduino Unos, and I want to make them can communicate via SPI, It's like they can send & receive data type (ping IP address each other). If that scenario can running well, is it possible I can ping Shield one and Shield two? 
(without router/switch, for this IoT research I still used local network, each Arduino w/ Shield plug to each laptop via RJ45 & USB port of course)

Topology:

```
Laptop A <===> Arduino Uno w/ Ethernet Shield <---> Arduino Uno w/ Ethernet Shield <===> Laptop B.
```

Note:

> ```
> <===> = RJ45
> <---> = Wire jumper (SPI or Pin 13 12 11 10, GND)
> ```

Sorry for my bad language, I didn't speak English well..

Can anyone help me?
Thank you,

H.